# How to reset/delete Qcustomplot's axis ticker setting?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qcustomplot

I have a QcustomPlot widget that I want to reuse it for plotting all kinds of plot. But there is a case that I need to set the xAxis ticker to DateTime.So I did this:

```
QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerDateTime> dateTicker(new QCPAxisTickerDateTime);
dateTicker->setDateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
customplot->xAxis->setTicker(dateTicker);
```

It changed the widget xAxis ticker forever. So when I want to switch it to other plots. The xAxis will always be 1970-01-01 on every tick. How do I reset the axis ticker setting to default/normal number setting?

I've tride:

```
customplot->clearPlottables();
customplot->xAxis->setRange(0,5);
customplot->replot;
```

but none of them worked. They only cleared the plot but not the xAixs ticks.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTicker(QSharedPointer(new QCPAxisTicker)); - this will return them to their standard state

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Your idea works. However it should be `ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTicker(QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTicker>(new QCPAxisTicker));`